# Custom PHP Event Calendar Help

Tags: php, calendar

I'm making a custom event calendar with PHP. I am trying to get the current day box to show up white, to let the user know that's the current day. I have all the `<td>` boxes with an id of `row-calendar-cell` and I want a way to detect that the certain box is the current  day and to change the id to `current-day`. Any help on that?

Also, I really am not sure how to display the day numbers in the right boxes...to be honest. Can anybody give a simple idea on how to do this?

Thanks a ton for any help!

Dixon

Comment: Please post your code. Don't make us stab in the dark. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest ideas I can give you:
1. Calendar presentation layer is rendered on the client - use a client side library for the calendar (i.e. JS and not PHP).
If you insist on PHP use on of the thousands all ready written.
2. I believe you meant you give all the cells a **class** and not **id** as id is for one, and only one, item in a page.

Comment: I've just decided to take a calendar and modify it to suit my needs. Thanks anyway.